# How can I write a terrain into a .raw file?

Tags: c, terrain, perlin-noise, heightmap

I want to generate a terrain through Perlin noise and store it into a .raw file.

From [Nehe's HeightMap tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/beautiful_landscapes_by_means_of_height_mapping/16006/) I know the .raw file is read like this:

```
#define MAP_SIZE        1024    

void LoadRawFile(LPSTR strName, int nSize, BYTE *pHeightMap)
{
    FILE *pFile = NULL;

    // Let's open the file in Read/Binary mode.
    pFile = fopen( strName, "rb" );

    // Check to see if we found the file and could open it
    if ( pFile == NULL )    
    {
        // Display our error message and stop the function
        MessageBox(NULL, "Can't find the height map!", "Error", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    // Here we load the .raw file into our pHeightMap data array.
    // We are only reading in '1', and the size is the (width * height)
    fread( pHeightMap, 1, nSize, pFile );

    // After we read the data, it's a good idea to check if everything read fine.
    int result = ferror( pFile );

    // Check if we received an error.
    if (result)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Can't get data!", "Error", MB_OK);
    }

    // Close the file.
    fclose(pFile);
```

}

`pHeightMap` is one-dimensional, so I don't understand how I would write the x,y correspondence to a height value.  I was planning to use either [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html) or the [noise2 function on Ken Perlin's page](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/doc/oscar.html), to make each value in a 1024x1024 matrix correspond to the height for the point, but the .raw file is stored in a single dimension, how can I make x,y correspondence work there?

Comment: See how it's used in the `Height` function.

Answer (score 1):

Let A be a 2-dimensional array with equal dimensions:

```
A[3][3] = {
            {'a', 'b', 'c'},
            {'d', 'e', 'f'},
            {'g', 'h', 'i'}
          }
```

You could also design this matrix as a single-dimension array:

```
A[9] = {
         'a', 'b', 'c',
         'd', 'e', 'f',
         'g', 'h', 'i'
       }
```

In the first case (2-dimension), you access the first element in the second array using a notation similar to `A[1][0]`. However, in the second case (1-dimension), you would access the same element using a notation similar to `A[1 * n + 0]`, where `n` is the length of each of the logically contained arrays, 3 in this case. Note that you still use the same index values (1 and 0), but for the single-dimensional case you have to include that multiplier `n` for the offset.